# How to get the macOS “.zip” icons to go back to the original macOS default “.zip” icon

Tags: macos, icons, zip

I'm running a brand new install of macOS Catalina and I changed my default application for unzipping files from Archive Utility (built into macOS) to [Archiver](https://archiverapp.com) by Incredible Bee.

I right clicked on a `.zip` file, “Get Info -> Open With” set it to “Archiver” and clicked “Change All.” Now all of my archives look like this:

[image: zip icon broken 1]

When I switch it back to the macOS “Archive Utility” using the same method it looks like this:

[image: zip icon broken 2]

Is there any way to get it back to the default look?

[image: zip icon fixed]

I even went back to “Get Info” to try and delete the thumbnail by pressing delete key but to no avail:

[image: zip icon get info]

Answer (score 0):

This is an unwilling bug in Catalina.

First you need to make the Archiver app as default application to open zip files - follow the method you mentioned above. Then, uncheck zip checkbox in "Archiver preferences" -> "File Types".

If it doesn't work, uninstall Archiver app and install it again.